# Django Chartit doesn't display on Ubuntu with wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, charts, mod-wsgi

I'm getting an important problem with `Django Chartit` in my project on `Ubuntu 15.04`.

I have two projects :

- I'm developping my Django website on **OSX as a developement platform**.
- I send my Django project on an **Ubuntu server** when it works owith OSX in order to make some tests. Ubuntu will be the operating system used by my project to the end. Ubuntu part looks like my product platform.

So, I'm using Django-chartit in order to display some graphics, ... and it works fine with OSX.

But when I copied my project to Ubuntu, I changed paths according to the OS, ... charts don't display on my website.

I used `python wsgi/apache2` with Ubuntu to display my Django website.

This is what I have :

**File 1 : apache2.conf**

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/Etat_civil/static/Theme/

<Directory /var/www/html/Etat_civil/static/Theme/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/Etat_civil/Etat_civil/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/Etat_civil


<Directory /var/www/html/Etat_civil/Etat_civil>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        SetEnvIfNoCase Host .+ VALID_HOST
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from env=VALID_HOST
        </Files>
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>


LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

**File 2 : My Django project**

I have some applications in my Django Project like this :

**Path :** /var/www/html/Etat_civil/

**Applications :** Accueil, BirthCertificate, ..., static, templates

**static directory :** /var/www/html/Etat_civil/static/Theme/Datasystems or Cameroun/js/

**File 3 : View functions which create charts**

In my application Identity, I have a function which creates 3 charts :

```
def Chartview(request) :

    #Step 1: Create a DataPool with the data we want to retrieve.
    weatherdata = \
        DataPool(
           series=
            [{'options': {
               'source': Person.objects.values('city').annotate(nombre = Count('city'))},
              'terms': [
                'city',
                'nombre']}
             ])

    #Step 2: Create the Chart object
    cht = Chart(
            datasource = weatherdata,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'pie',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'city': [
                    'nombre']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': "Nombre d'habitant par ville"},
                'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Villes'}}})


    ds = \
        DataPool(
           series=
            [{'options': {
               'source': Person.objects.values('birthcountry').annotate(nombre = Count('birthcountry'))},
              'terms': [
                'birthcountry',
                'nombre']}
             ])

    #Step 2: Create the Chart object
    cht2 = Chart(
            datasource = ds,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'pie',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'birthcountry': [
                    'nombre']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': "Proportion des Pays de Naissance"},
                'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Pays de Naissance'}}})


    ds2 = \
        DataPool(
           series=
            [{'options': {
               'source': Person.objects.values('sex').annotate(nombre = Count('sex'))},
              'terms': [
                'sex',
                'nombre']}
             ])

    #Step 2: Create the Chart object
    cht3 = Chart(
            datasource = ds2,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'column',
                  'stacking': False},
                'terms':{
                  'sex': [
                    'nombre']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': "Nombre Homme/Femme"},
                'xAxis': {
                    'title': {
                       'text': 'Sexe'}}})

    return render(request, 'statistics.html', {'charts': [cht, cht2, cht3],})
```

And I have a template file :

```
{% extends 'Base_Identity.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}


{% block title %}
    <h2 align="center"> Statistiques </align> </h2>
{% endblock %}

<br></br>

{% block content %}

    {% block javascript %}
    <script src="{% static 'Datasystems/js/jquery-3.1.1.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Datasystems/js/highcharts/highcharts.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endblock %}

    {% load chartit %}
    {{ charts|load_charts:"cht, cht2, cht3" }}

<div class="col-md-5">
    <div id="cht"> TEST  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-5">
    <div id="cht2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <br></br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="cht3"></div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

This entire script works very well with OSX, but on Ubuntu I don't overcome to display charts. I'm sure it's a path problem but I checked all the day and I don't find where an error could be possible.

Comment: I have the chartit path like this : `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chartit/static/chartit/js/chartitloaders.js`. If I copy `chartit/js/chartitloaders.js` in my Django static directory, it seems to work but it's pretty strange for me.

Comment: Did you run ``python manage.py collectstatic`` on the target system? Is there an installed app for Django for ChartIt which would even copy the static files in to the correct place when you run ``collectstatic``?

Comment: I didn't run `collectstatic`. I have to do that in order to not copy `chartit` directory in my Project ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'have to do that in order to NOT copy'. The ``collectstatic`` command is what puts all the static assets into one place so they can be served up by a web server such as Apache.